# Load file with AJAX and append to

Tags: jquery, ajax, append

On this test page:

http://sapaacademy.net/working/jQueryAjaxExercises.html

1) click on first button `<a class="btn_quizTEST"  data-exercisename="FL1E1.html">Start Exercise I </a>`- see 1st file loaded

2) click on 2nd button `<a class="btn_quizTEST"  data-exercisename="FL1E2.html">Start Exercise II </a>`- see 1st file **overriden** with 2nd

3) click 3rd button `<a class="btn_quizTEST"  data-exercisename="SL1E3.html">Start Exercise III </a>`-- see all previous loaded files **overriden**

I know it's because of:

```
   $.ajax({
    // code...
 success:function(result){
      $('.exspace').html(result); <-- overrides all other loaded files
    }});
```

How do I prevent overriding and append a file to corresponding field?

FL1E1.html should load only into it's corresponding div

FL1E2.html should load into it's corresponding div

SL1E3.html should load into it's corresponding div

Any advice would be appreciated

```
  <script> </script> is in the DOM
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't you just change `html()` with `append()` ?

```
var self = this;

$.ajax({
    // code...
   success:function(result){
       $(self).closest('.exBtnWrap').find('.exspace').append(result);
   }
});
```

Comment: Just changed to .append(). See new behaviour. Still wrong. Beucase the script traverses and selects ALL $('.exspace') DIVs. :(

Comment: @AndreyDoronin - Of course it does, what element do you want to target, it's not really clear as you haven't added any markup. I edited the answer to try and give a very general solution.

Comment: For button 1 I have file 1, for button 2 -- file 2, for button 3 -- file 3. But all buttons have same $('.exspace') DIVs into which file loads. I need to traverse and target somehow the corresponding $('.expsace') without affecting others.

Comment: @AndreyDoronin - Yes, that's exactly what you need to do, but without seeing the markup it's impossible to tell you how to do that, you'll have to figure it out. Did you try the code above ?

Comment: YES! It works! Thank you! I tried the code after your Edit. But I tried precisely that (closest()+find()), and it didnt work... I had --> ` var visibleExField = $(this).closest('.exBtnWrap').find('.exspace');  visibleExField.closest('.exBtnWrap').find('.exspace').append(result);`

Answer (score 1):

For each div create id and and code ajax like this,

```
function loadFile(id){
$.ajax({
// code...
success:function(result){
  $('#'+id).html(result); <-- overrides all other loaded files
}});
}

<a class="btn_quizTEST" data-exercisename="FL1E1.html" id="file1"    
      onclick="loadFile(this.id)">Start Exercise I </a>
```

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to figure out how to traverse correctly adeneo above figured it out. The solution with IDs must be also good, but the above traversing solution requires less mark-up (giving IDs). Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

As i see your page you have a `setTimeout()` method which has jQuery's `.slideDown()` method, so you can do your ajax call in the `.slideDown()`'s callback function:

```
var $this = $(this);

setTimeout(function () {
    $('.exspace').slideDown('fast', function(){
          $.ajax({
             // code...
          success:function(result){
                $this.closest('.exBtnWrap').find('.exspace').html(result);
          }});
    });
}, 500);
```

Comment: Yes! That's what I was trying, traverse up and back down. I tried your suggestion, but it still overrides... --->  [http://sapaacademy.net/working/jQueryAjaxExercises1.html]